# how to make random image compare

Tags: vb.net

I want the same picture to display a msgbox called "Ok". Even if the same picture comes out, the MsgBox displays "No".

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim a, b As Object
        a = PictureBox1.Image
        b = PictureBox2.Image
        If a Is b Then
            MsgBox("Ok")
        Else
            MsgBox("No")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\gg.png")
        PictureBox2.Image = PictureBox1.Image
        PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\ww.png")
        PictureBox2.Image = PictureBox1.Image
        PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\aa.jfif")
        PictureBox2.Image = PictureBox1.Image
        PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\bb.jfif")
        PictureBox2.Image = PictureBox1.Image
        PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\c.jfif")
        PictureBox2.Image = PictureBox1.Image
        PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\ss.jfif")
        PictureBox2.Image = PictureBox1.Image
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Randomize()

ReRnd:
        Dim r1 As Object = Int(Rnd(1) * 6) + 1
        Dim r2 As Object = Int(Rnd(1) * 6) + 1
        Select Case r1
            Case 1
                PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\gg.png")
                Exit Select
            Case 2
                PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\ww.png")
                Exit Select
            Case 3
                PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\aa.jfif")
                Exit Select
            Case 4
                PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\bb.jfif")
                Exit Select
            Case 5
                PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\c.jfif")
                Exit Select
            Case 6
                PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\ss.jfif")
                Exit Select
        End Select

        Select Case r2
            Case 1
                PictureBox2.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\gg.png")
                Exit Select
            Case 2
                PictureBox2.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\ww.png")
                Exit Select
            Case 3
                PictureBox2.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\aa.jfif")
                Exit Select
            Case 4
                PictureBox2.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\bb.jfif")
                Exit Select
            Case 5
                PictureBox2.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\c.jfif")
                Exit Select
            Case 6
                PictureBox2.Image = New Bitmap("C:\vb\pic_compare\ss.jfif")
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You could safely remove each `Exit Select` in your code. VB.Net does not fall through the `Select` & will only execute the matching `Case`.

Comment: Randomizing at the same time will probably give you the same value for both, try making it static instead of just dim. Btw the things you're doing on formLoad does nothing cause that happens on click, if it is for the visuals you can keep last 2 lines from it. And as ItsPete said exit select does nothing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you keep creating new `Bitmap` objects all the time.  If you create two different `Bitmap` objects from the same file then they are two different objects, so testing whether one `Is` the other will obviously be `False`, hence the result you see.

What you should be doing is just creating a single `Bitmap` object from each file and storing those for reuse.  Logically, you should store them in an array and then you can use the random numbers you generate as indexes into that array.  If you use the same `Bitmap` object in both `PictureBoxes` then one `Is` the other and you'll get the result you want.

For a real life example of why what you're doing is wrong, consider the scenario where you and I go to a car dealer and by a car each that are the same in every way.  Does that mean that my car IS your car and vice versa?  Of course not.  They are two different cars that were made the same.  That's what you're doing with your `Bitmap` objects.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private rng As New Random
    Private images As Bitmap()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim folderPath = "C:\vb\pic_compare"

        images = {New Bitmap(Path.Combine(folderPath, "gg.png")),
                  New Bitmap(Path.Combine(folderPath, "ww.png")),
                  New Bitmap(Path.Combine(folderPath, "aa.jfif")),
                  New Bitmap(Path.Combine(folderPath, "bb.jfif")),
                  New Bitmap(Path.Combine(folderPath, "c.jfif")),
                  New Bitmap(Path.Combine(folderPath, "ss.jfif"))}
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim max = images.Length
        Dim index1 = rng.Next(max)
        Dim index2 = rng.Next(max)

        PictureBox1.Image = images(index1)
        PictureBox2.Image = images(index2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If PictureBox1.Image Is PictureBox2.Image Then
            MessageBox.Show("OK")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        'Dispose the Images to release the files.
        For Each bmp In images
            bmp.Dispose()
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I have added code.  Among other things, it generates random numbers the "proper" way, i.e. via the `Random` class.